# communicate between a pc to other pc . mysql workbench 8.0

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, server, workbench

I have a java application running on NetBeans 8.0 and I setup other pc with MySQL server 8.0 . I want them to establish connection but I cannot . BTW I am using Windows OS

I've tried propably everything.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:/127.0.0.1:3306/ims?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false","root","advance");
System.out.println("Connection Success");
return conn;
```

I want the two PC to communicate.

Comment: FYI: NetBeans is an IDE, you're propably running your app on some default server; `127.0.0.1` is localhost, you need to find IP in your local network

Comment: @barbsan tq sir..can u teach to set mysql workbench..which is for remote server purpose..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your connection string you're indicating `127.0.0.1:3306` as the destination you're trying to reach. That is an IP address and port of the MySQL server that Java is trying to connect to. But you said you have *another PC* running MySQL.

`127.0.0.1` is a shortcut way of saying "myself" or "localhost"; so you're telling the Java application to look at *the same PC* to find a MySQL server. It's failing because MySQL isn't there, it's on another PC.

To solve this, you'll need to find the IP address of the PC that the MySQL server is running on, and replace `127.0.0.1` with that other PC's IP address (and verify that the MySQL server is using port `3306`).

Comment: i see..tq so much sir..how about mysql workbench which is the other one pc.. i need to set with it self IP also? @MidnightLightning

Comment: @ShahrainSoffi: Yes, same thing for configuring MySQL Workbench as for configuring your Java app: it will need to know the IP address of the running MySQL server to connect to.

Comment: MidnightLightning i see tq vm.. btw.. if for remotely access db..is it 3306 port or else..

Comment: Sure thing! If this answer helped you, you can click the green checkmark near the voting buttons for this answer to mark it as "accepted"

Comment: MidnightLightning tq so much sir. my problem has resolved . tq again